# Getting an error when I copy files image files to drawable

Tags: java, android

I copied two images in the folder `drawable-hdpi`,`-ldpi`,`-mdpi` and referenced that image to a button.

I'm getting following error in my console: **" No resource found matching the give name"**.

What am I doing wrong?"hello" is the name of the image i referenced from the resource folder.i m getting the error the moment i add the image in the resource folder even before referencing the image to the button.

```
 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/button2" 
  android:text=""
  android:background="@drawable/hello"
   android:layout_x="190dp"
    android:layout_y="220dip">
    </Button>
```

Comment: can you please post images name that you copied

Comment: please provide a code example

Comment: Are you developing for Android 1.5?
The -hdpi, -mdpi, -ldpi folders were included in 1.6 The image name is hello.png? Are you sure the image has valid characters? Is the image is a 9-patch? maybe is wrong.

Comment: i  m using android 2.3.3. i tried adding different image image named as Default.png getting the same error.the second i add my image..cud u explain me wat is 9-patch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" 
        android:background="@null"
/>
```

If still you have the problem ,try to clean the project and run it.

Comment: nope...just by adding the .png file in my resource folder i m getting error,even before referencing the image to my button as you shown above

Comment: please ensure that there is no capital Letters in your image name.

Comment: bingo!.found the solution.the problem is with my image.its a .jpg image which is renamed as .png.created a new .png image in photoshop and it worked..thanks for your efforts freshDroid

Answer (score 1):

did you try to access the images by id

```
R.drawable.your_image
```

accessing resources by name is possible from the Assets folder.

Comment: i m getting the error if i just add the image in my res folder..without even referencing the image to the button..any thought

Comment: android:background="@drawable/hello" - if there is no resource file in drawable (hello.png for ex.) you should get error. Do you have file with that name in your drawable folder?

Comment: yup i do have with the name hello.png ..forget abt referencing to the button.if i m to copy the image to the assets folder..i m getting an error that "No resource found that matches the given name(at 'src' value '@drawable/icon')"

Comment: in your code, Button btn = findViewById(R.id.yourButton); btn.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);

Comment: the thing is the moment i copy my .png file from my desktop  to res folder i m getting error..any aidea

Comment: Ok, lets make it clear - you should put your image in your drawable folder. Let's name that image "your_image.png. If you want to reference it from XML layout, you reference it like android:background="@drawable/your_image", if you want to do it from code - btn.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);

Comment: k i totally get wat u r trying to tell me and it is possible..but the problem dat  i face is i m getting error if i m to add the image file in my res folder in the first..

Comment: I don't get it, you want to add the image to the res "root"... why?

Comment: as u said i added my image in assets folder.. i m not getting error.how to make a reference to the image coz R.drawable.image wont work since the image is in my assets folder

Comment: Found the solution .the problem is with my image.its a .jpg image which is renamed with the extension .png.created a new .png image in photoshop and it worked..thanks for your efforts mihal

Answer (score 1):

in XML you also need to add the type of the reference:

```
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

Comment: i m getting an error the moment i add my .png file in res folder..even before referencing the image to button..any idea

Answer (score 0):

did you use this notation.

```
R.drawable.nostatusindicator
```

Where nostatusindicator is the file in your drawable directory in `-hdpi`, `-mdpi`, `-ldpi` and please check that you **should not have capital letters** in the names and also not extravagent **characters except underscore** in names of those files.

Update: after having a look at your code  and it seems good. just clean build it once again. and assuming that your files are in atleast one of the folder of `drawable-hdpi`,`-ldpi`,`-mdpi`.... or restart the eclipse application.

Clean and Run: when in eclipse open the project menu and press clean  and then run(The Build is done automatically as specified in the build automatically in the project)the project as you would normally do for any application to be tested on your emulator. this clears out the build files which might sometimes do not get updated for small changes like image addition or something like that... you even say you have a conflict when you are trying to add the images to it....

Comment: if the file names are invalid, the project will not compile

Comment: cud u gimme a small example of dat

Comment: @kingston: Please use proper English spelling, slang is frown upon here.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code below into the MainActivity class and copy the images to the dhpi folder with ic_launcher, ic_launcher2, ic_launcher3 and ic_1 as the image names respectively, you can also change the size, width and height.

```
 int array_image[] = {
     R.drawable.ic_launcher,
     R.drawable.ic_launcher2,
     R.drawable.ic_launcher3,
     R.drawable.ic_1
}
```